# Login Page Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

i am new to CodeIgniter and i'm trying to make a login page. In my case, i want if wrong password or email get the flashdata and if true will go to another page. I'm trying to input wrong email and password but it just refresh the page without show flashdata and i'm trying to input correct email and password it just refresh the page and not redirect to another page.

this my model code (M_login.php):

```
public function get_user_by_email($user_email)
    {
        $data = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('user')
            ->where('user_email', $user_email)
            ->get()
            ->row();
        return $data;
    }
```

my controller(Login.php) :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('M_login');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('template/login', '', true);
        $this->load->view('template/layout', $data);
    }

    public function customer_login()
    {
        $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email', true);
        $user_pass = md5($this->input->post('user_pswd', true));
        $user_detail = $this->M_login->get_user_by_email($user_email);
        if ($user_pass == $user_detail->user_pswd) {
            $sdata['user_id'] = $user_detail->user_id;
            $sdata['user_name'] = $user_detail->user_name;
            $sdata['user_email'] = $user_detail->user_email;
            $sdata['user_id'] = $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
            redirect("billing");
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_msg', 'Password atau Email anda salah........!');
            redirect("Login/login");
        }
    }
```

my view(login.php):

```
<form action=" <?= base_url() ?>customer_login" method="post">
            <section class=" my-3">
                <input class="input is-rounded is-medium" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Masukan e-mail anda">
            </section>
            <section class="my-3">
                <input class="input is-rounded is-medium" type="password" name="user_pswd" placeholder="Masukkan password anda">
            </section>
            <section class="mt-4 ml-2">
                <button class="button is-danger" type="submit">Login</button>
            </section>
            </form>
```

this my db :
[db user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp6w5.png)

Comment: use this $data = $this->db->get_where('user',array('user_email'=>$user_email,'user_pswd'=>$user_pass))->row_array();
        return $data; & let me know please.

Comment: and remove `md5()` from this  `$user_pass = $this->input->post('user_pswd', true);` because you dont store password in encyrpted form.

Comment: @KUMAR same of my first code nothing happen

Comment: @KUMAR its work yap, the problem on md5. Then i check my db that user_pswd is not varchar 32. Then i change the length to 32 and use the md5 and finally it's work. The problem now just the flash_msg not showed. Thank for your help. Appreciate it

Comment: you should start a session , set session , display session in view according to my code,

Comment: @KUMAR Yap done yet thank for your answer. Appreciate it

Comment: if this answers help you please give me upvote.

Answer (score 0):

**view(login.php):-**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>Login/customer_login" method="POST">
    <?php 
    if( $this->session->flashdata('err_message') )
    {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('err_message');
    }
    ?>
<section class=" my-3">
    <input class="input is-rounded is-medium" type="email" name="user_email" placeholder="Masukan e-mail anda">
</section>
<section class="my-3">
    <input class="input is-rounded is-medium" type="password" name="user_pswd" placeholder="Masukkan password anda">
</section>
<section class="mt-4 ml-2">
    <button class="button is-danger">Login</button>
</section>
</form>
```

**controller(Login.php) :-**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('M_login');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('template/login', '', true);
        $this->load->view('template/layout', $data);
    }

    public function customer_login()
    {
        $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email', true);
        $user_pass = md5($this->input->post('user_pswd', true));
        $user_result = $this->M_login->get_user($user_email,$user_pass);
        if ($user_result >0) //active user record is present
            {
           $this->session->set_userdata('user_session',$user_result);

           $this->session->set_flashdata('login_message', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Login to your account!</div>');
            
            $url = base_url('Login/billing');
            redirect($url);
            
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid email and password!</div>');
            redirect("Login/login");
        }
    }
    
    public function billing()
    {
    $this->load->view('user_billing_dashboard');
    }
    
}
```

**Model M_login:-**

```
class M_login extends CI_Model {
public function get_user($user_email,$user_pass)
    {
  $data = $this->db->get_where('user',array('user_email'=>$user_email,'user_pswd'=>$user_pass))->row_array();
    return $data;
    } 
}
```

**Create View:-**

**user_billing_dashboard.php**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <?php 
   if($this->session->flashdata('login_message')){
 ?>
   <div class="alert alert-success"  style="display:none;"> 
     <?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('login_message'); ?>
<?php    
} else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
?>
 <div class = "alert alert-danger"  style="display:none;">
   <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried you code but show error like this
`Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `email` = 'test2@gmail.com' AND `password` = 'c06db68e819be6ec3d26c6038d8e8d1f'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/GreyCI/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`

and i try change the model like this :
` $data = $this->db->get_where('user', array('user_email' => $user_email, 'user_pswd' => $user_pass))->row_array();
        return $data;`
not seem error, but the result back like my first code

Comment: use this `$data = $this->db->get_where('user',array('user_email'=>$user_email,'password'=>$user_pass))->row_array();`

Comment: show error like this 
`Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'password' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_email` = 'test2@gmail.com' AND `password` = 'c06db68e819be6ec3d26c6038d8e8d1f'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/GreyCI/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`